Is it possible to export my Zoom client's settings?
The Zoom / Zoom Workplace client app has a bunch of settings, but doesn't seem to offer a way of exporting them.
Can I export those settings without, say, replicating my entire %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Zoom directory?

You can always use Everything to track file changes yourself. Set it up to sort by lost modified date in descending manner, then you could also filter by zoom while including the path for lookup.
You'll then notice that e.g.:

changing theme modifies data\Zoom.us.ini
modifying some other settings changes client.config file in a dir with garbled name
data\zoomus.enc.db database gets updated occassionally, not entirely sure if it contains any settings though

The conclusion is that the application, at least current version 6.2.7, definitely isn't made with backing up settings through files in mind. I can't also see any changes in registry. And there's 100% no option to export settings in any menu.

I observed on 6.1.6 (43767) that at least some settings are stored exclusively in the encrypted database, zoomus.enc.db. For example, the Enable global shortcut checkboxes under Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts.
I tested this by making a backup of zoomus.enc.db, changing the setting in the UI, quitting Zoom, and then restoring this file from my backup. The original setting got restored when I did this.
These settings are also not available on https://zoom.us/profile/setting.
Zoom is doing all they can to make their product unusable.

No for personal account. When you are switching to a new device the client settings are reset to default.
However, you can do this with a corporate account under administrator. You need to contact Zoom and ask them to add a report called Settings Snapshot. This allows you to export a csv file with the current settings.

"The client settings are reset to default" - but they are saved somewhere. IIANM, that's in some of the files under the directory I mentioned. Wouldn't overwriting files using files from the old profile be sufficient?

@einpoklum - It's more than likely a registry setting not a file. Have you tried your theory? I am guessing it won't work.
